# Как правильно отправить POST запрос с fetch и formData?

Tags: javascript

Как отправлять данные методом fetch, чтобы они в network были в таком виде
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

делаю так

```
return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: formData
})
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(resp=> {
    if (respObj.resultCode !== 'OK') {
        throw new Error());
    }
    return resp;
});
```

но данные представлены в таком виде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: откуда сделал первый скриншот? покажи как ты инициализируешь переменную formData

Comment: [What does WebKitFormBoundary mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41188903/2881286)

Comment: скриншот с сайта. доступа к  коду нет

Comment: если к коду доступа нет, откуда отрывок в вопросе?

Comment: второй скриншот относится к куску кода(доступ к коду есть, кусок представлен в вопросе). Нужно отправлять в таком виде, как на сайте (первый скриншот)

Comment: я инициализирую переменную как
const formData = new FormData();
и забиваю данные так

            formData.append('v_subject', '1234444');
 formData.append('v_subject', '1234ппапапапа444');
и т.д. и отправляю frmData в body